# Html talk to C# application .netCF 2.0/3.5

Tags: c#, javascript, html, webserver, tcplistener

So I have a C# application, and I would like to remotely change values via a browser. I've been doing some digging and found embedded webserver that uses the TCPListener like this one: http://webserver.codeplex.com/ However, it's for .NET, and I'm working with CF. my goal is to have a static HTML page with some javascript on it. For example, button onclick... from HTML display string in C# via invoke or something. Is this possible? I have to do this remotely from another computer, and it will access this html page and make changes. I can't use ASP. Has anyone attempted this before?

Thanks!

Comment: This is still very vague. What kind of C# application?  What kind of architecture/design?  Why can't you use ASP?  How fast does the response need to be from the time you click your html button to the time it updates the application?  Are you update objects or a database? If this isn't a web application, and you aren't using a web service or WCF, then you have a lot of work to do. And of course, the most common SO question: What have you already tried?

Comment: @GrayFox374 I'm building an application on wince 6 that runs on a mini2440/mini210 ARM based, and I need access to system's serial ports and SPI/I2C ports. The response time can be pretty slow. I'm updating a class called DB with many public static variables. I've never written a webapplication before, so taking the ASP route would be somewhat scary. Also I would want to access the program via my  phone, so I'm not so sure about asp's compatibility. I know that html works on everything.

Comment: Okay, I had to look some things up.  You're mini2440/mini210 is an embedded system with no hard drive and a very minimal implementation of Windows on it, correct?  You are developing a C# application that will be deploying to this device?  Is this a winforms app or a console app?  Will this device have have web access? What do you need access to the ports to accomplish?  And where is this web page being hosted?

Comment: @GrayFox374 Yes, this is correct (but it's actually faster than some desktop computers that I have). So far, I've written everything on WinForms since I can easily access SPI/I2C/Serial via System.IO.Ports. It has a decent looking gui. This device may or may not have internet access. If no access to internet, then save to a XML file using System.XML. If there is interenet, then connect to a MySQL server using the MySQL connector for compact framework. I need the access to the ports since I have multiple devices running on different ports (serial/I2C/SPI) to gather analog data.

Comment: I'm thinking of hosting the page on the device itself. The specs of the device is surprisingly good: 1GHz, 512MB ram, 4GB NAND. It's a speedy little monster I tell you.

Comment: So when you say remotely change the values via a browser, I think you need a web service, which means you need a web server.  Since your app will not always be online, you can't remotely update the values with a web service to maybe store the values in a db, and when you open your app, update values from the db if there are new changes.

Comment: @GrayFox374. Hey, I've found a good link that might help me implement such design: [compact webserver WINCE](http://bansky.net/blog/2007/10/compact-web-server-in-compact-framework/). As of now, he's only implemented the GET but not POST. I think I can build something on top and develop POST.